# has_secure_password not Encrypting password_digest Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption

I have commented everything out of my model except:

```
has_secure_password
```

and with my migration I have added:

```
t.string "password_digest"
```

to my users database.

When I create a user in the rails console and try to save it however, the password doesn't encrypt. It appears in my database as the password that I entered. Could someone please tell me how to get has_secure_password to encrypt my password? Am I missing something simple? I have the bcrypt gem installed.

Comment: Answering your own questions is okay. Self-learning for the win. Just do it properly: write an answer (and how you found it) and accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. For others that come by this post and aren't quite sure what you mean.

You don't assign a password to **password_digest**

You assign it to **password**

When you add **has_secure_password** to your model, it automatically adds a *virtual attribute* called **password**. When you assign a value to password, it will encrypt and save into **password_digest**.

Answer (score 0):

ANSWERED: I needed to use the virtual password attribute not the password_digest attribute

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else gets here with a different problem. We were trying to use this with ember (à la http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/jwt-authentication-with-rails-ember-part-i-rails-knock/ ) and our problem was (pretty much the same as the answerers indicated above) that we added `passwordDigest` to our ember data model (so we were essentially assigning to `password_digest` rather than `password`, but ember data was doing it on our behalf so we didn't realize it at first from the answers above).

Answer (score 0):

`t.string :password_digest`   perhaps rollback your migration and place this in your migration file. I hope this helps.

Comment: kindly consider adding more information in your answer